# Python - AttributeError: Point instance has no attribute 'x'

Tags: python

So I'm making a point class which I'll use to draw shapes. I'm starting by creating my points and raising an error if the x and y values are not floats:

```
def __init__(self, x, y):
    if not isinstance(x, float):
        raise Error ("Parameter \"x\" illegal.")        
        if not isinstance(y, float):
            raise Error ("Parameter \"y\" illegal.")
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
```

And then in this method I'm converting the values to an int in string form.

```
def __str__(self):
    return int(round(self.x))
```

The problem is for the above method, it's giving me the error:

```
AttributeError: Point instance has no attribute 'x'
```

However x should exist so I don't know why it's giving me that error. Even if I use y it says y doesn't exist. So why is that method giving me this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the indentation in the question is actually correct, `x` and `y` are never set. The code states:

```
    if not isinstance(y, float):
        raise Error ("Parameter \"y\" illegal.")
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

If the `if` evaluates to `True`, an exception will be raised, and the lines will never be reached. If it evaluates to `False`, then this whole block is not executed.

You might have meant this:

```
if not isinstance(x, float):
    raise Error ("Parameter \"x\" illegal.")        
self.x = x
if not isinstance(y, float):
    raise Error ("Parameter \"y\" illegal.")
self.y = y
```

Comment: That fixed one problem but now I'm getting another error that says TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type int)

Comment: You really ought to have opened a separate question on that (it's unrelated), but I guess you want `return str(int...)`. Your `__str__` method indeed needs to return a string.

Answer (score 1):

You're only initializing `x` and `y` only if you raise an error - or never.

You want something like:

```
def __init__(self, x, y):
    if not isinstance(x, float):
        raise Error ("Parameter \"x\" illegal.")        
    if not isinstance(y, float):
        raise Error ("Parameter \"y\" illegal.")
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
```